# ASP.NET Profile

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-profiles

I have this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   nome_Txt.Text = Profile.dados_pessoais.nome;
}
```

```
protected void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Profile.dados_pessoais.nome = nome_Txt.Text;
}
```

If `Profile.dados_pessoais.nome` is empty, `nome_txt.Text` is empty too. When I change `nome_Txt.Text` to `teste` for example, when I click on the button `nome_Txt.Text` is empty.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why tag with asp classic? Fixed...

Comment: try to call `save()` method of `Profile` object `Profile.Save()`

Comment: @walther that is the first tag that appears when typing `asp`.. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Page_Load` event run before the button click event so you always assign the text box to empty value.

To solve this, don't populate the textbox when you are in a Postback:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        nome_Txt.Text = Profile.dados_pessoais.nome;
    }
}
```

As also stated in a comment, you probably have to save the profile after changing it otherwise it won't be saved when you next load the page:

```
protected void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Profile.dados_pessoais.nome = nome_Txt.Text;
    Profile.Save()
}
```

Comment: I think is not necessary Profile.Save(), because when you set for example Profile.dados_pessoais.nome = nome_Txt.Text, is save automatically in database

Comment: @Eriksson cheers, it depends on the implementation of `Profile`.